# How to flush model out of GPU in python without restarting kernel

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, torch

After training a model, I want to flush everything out from the GPU without restarting the kernel.

```
device = torch.device("cuda:1")
model = ...
model.to(device)
```

After training the model

```
with torch.cuda.device('cuda:1'):
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

After I execute the above commands, the GPU usage downgrades from 20 GB to 1626 MB.

My question is that why there is still 1626 MB in use?
Maybe it is the model taking up the space? How to flush it out of GPU?

Comment: Have you tried `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`?

Comment: @meti, Yeah, like I mentioned above, it downgrades from 20 GB to 1626 MB, and I am curious how to clean up the remaining 1626 MB (Maybe its the model taking up the space).